# Zumero error 1992: http_404

Tags: zumero

I've successfully configured ZSS Server on my internal system (Win Server 2008R2 + IIS 7.5), and everything works fine.

Now I'm trying to install the same system on a customer machine; I've done this through the installer (latest version), he has applied the necessary security permissions, the home page of the site is visible, but syncing the db give the 1992 error.

Taking a look at IIS logs, I see that every call with GET /pull result in a 404 error code, subcode 0; there are several consecutive statements like this, all terminating wi9th 404.0 error code.

The web.config is the same as my system. What else can I check ?

Answer (score 0):

You say you can reach the home page of the site - do you mean the "main" IIS home page, or the root of the ZSS site? That is, assuming Zumero is running on port 8080, what do you see when you point a browser at http://your.customer.site:8080?

Comment: It's the content of the index.html file under ZSS Server\www, reporting "Zumero for SQL Server, version 1.3.0.1880". We are testing the entire system over the internal network, in order to avoid router/firewall issues.

Comment: And you're certain that the client app is using the correct port? Actually, are you testing from a client device, or via ZSS Manager / the Test Client tool? Also, at this point it might be more effective to email <support@zumero.com> so we can see logs/etc.

Comment: I'm currently on a phone call with the customer, and we are obtaining the error also with the Test Client tool. I'll provide you with the log of the IIS failing the sync, and (if it can be of any help) the log of my working IIS. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue at a Customer site... Most likely security related

Answer (score 0):

I my case it was caused by the Application pool being configured for 32 bit (which it should not be). Version 1.4 has an improved installer, that should prevent this from happening